# Installing chromium on Raspbian

Tags: pi-2, software-installation, chromium

I was trying to install chromium on the RPi but it does not seems to be working. I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.

This is what i typed:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium
```

...and I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 chromium : Depends: chromium-inspector but it is not going to be installed
 skypeweb : Depends: libjson-glib-1.0-0 (>= 0.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libjson-glib-1.0-0 (>= 0.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Please advise on how to correct the problem.

Comment: What OS and version are you running? Have you tried the suggestion from the error message: Try `apt-get -f install chromium`?

Answer (score 1):

Follow its advice. Run `sudo apt-get -f install`

After that, re-run `sudo apt-get install chromium`

Answer (score -3):

For Raspberry Pis running Jessie you can install Chromium using this code.

```
    wget -qO - http://bintray.com/user/downloadSubjectPublicKey?username=bintray | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/kusti8/chromium-rpi jessie main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser rpi-youtube -y
```

Here is the link for more detailed instructions.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=121195

Comment: Don't just post a link, summarize the info in your answer. What if the link goes dead?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -5):

run apt-get -f install chromium-bsu

Comment: Some explanation of why this works and also what might have caused the original error would be nice to see...

Comment: `chromium-bsu` is a game. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_B.S.U.)